# To hide the parameters values passed in URL in apex

Tags: oracle-apex, apex-code

I am passing the parameters and its values from page 1 to page 2 using the link builder target method. But I want to hide all the parameters and the values in the URL(Instead of GET format, i want it in a POST format). How can this be done?

Thanks & Regards,
Nikita D.

Answer (score 2):

Links are... well, they're links to another pages so by definition they are urls and "GET" requests. If you link from one page to another using the link builder, that is what you get. That cannot be changed to a post request. However:

- Using a "branch" instead of a link will use a post request and not show anything in the url. Branches are executed after page processing on page submit.
- If branch is not an option: in the target page (page 2 in your case) set "page access protection" to "Arguments must have checksum". This affects any links that are configured in the link builder so the parameters will be in the url but there is also a checksum that prevents anyone from tampering with the url.

Comment: I think your second point is related to an outstanding question - *why* does Niki need to hide the values in the URL?